# Why applicationContext.xml property loading twice with outside Tomcat as Spring web project?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a running Spring web project (A) with outside Tomcat, and now, I want to move to Spring cloud, that need to support (A), and while I run as Spring boot web project with outside Tomcat, the applicationContext.xml loads twice.

Code as below:

```
package com.pa.openapi.gateway.core;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*********************Application***************************************");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(this.getClass());
    }
}


package com.pa.openapi.gateway.core;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath*:applicationContext.xml")
public class ConfigurationClass { }
```

Tomcat as apache-tomcat-8.0.24

If you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: How do you know it is loading the "file" twice? Remove `@ImportResource` for the file and see what happens.

Comment: while remove @ImportResource:                                                                          ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field enablerCacheService in com.pa.openapi.gateway.core.controller.GatwayCommonController required a bean of type 'com.pa.openapi.cache.core.buz.service.impl.EnablerCacheService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pa.openapi.cache.core.buz.service.impl.EnablerCacheService' in your configuration.

Comment: So I believe, you have your `com.pa.openapi.cache.core.buz.service.impl.EnablerCacheServ‌​ice` bean defined in the `applicationContext.xml`. Based on what you see above, this rules out `applicationContext.xml` being loaded from anywhere else in your code. So same question, how do you determine that it is being loaded twice?

Comment: Also do you really have it as `classpath*:applicationContext.xml` or is that * a typo here? I guess it should be `classpath:applicationContext.xml`, considering the file is in your application classpath.

Comment: not ablout classpath* or not , not with * ,also loading twice,all the property file loading twice

Comment: INFO  [2017-09-27 17:45:47,658] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] 
 

 INFO  [2017-09-27 17:47:21,046] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml] 
 

and others also as the same

Comment: There is a time difference of 2 seconds, in your logs. I wonder if it has something to do with how you're packaging the application. Do you see Spring boot splash screen, also twice in your logs? Also @EnableWebMvc should not be needed as Spring boot should automatically load it when it sees spring-webmvc jar in your classpath.

Comment: no mater with EnableWebMvc,I use this for other function，while i remove EnableWebMvc,also loading twice(spring boot web project)，the log shows loading one time and second time

Comment: Ok then check a few things: First, in your maven dependencies ensure `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is defined with `scope` as `provided`. Second look at your logs and see if it is actually spinning up a whole new Servlet container, as that is what I think is happening. See what port it shows. See if you have `management.port` defined in your application

Comment: I have resolved this issue ,                                             EnableWebMvc
SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
  HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
EnableDiscoveryClient
public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {......}           and with                                                                    @Configuration
PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),@PropertySource("classpath:bootstrap.properties")})
public class ConfigurationClass {}

Comment: @Gautam,thanks ~~!

Comment: Please care to explain what the issue was. I couldn't stay for longer on this, as I called it a day.

Comment: spring cloud project outside tomcat ,as main class with implements WebApplicationInitializer and @Configuration PropertySources({@PropertySource("classpath:application.prop‌​erties"),@PropertySo‌​urce("classpath:boot‌​strap.properties")}) public class ConfigurationClass {} can resolve this issue